# Что значит ошибка error C2065: 'cout': undeclared identifier?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Пишу программу и вылетает такая ошибка:

> error C2065: 'cout': undeclared identifier;

В чём может быть причина?

Вот программа:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
#include "stdafx.h"
void main()
{
  int a, b ;

  cout << "Enter f-st n-bre"  ;

  cin >> a  ;

  cout << "second";

  cin >> b ;

  cout << "sum is " << a+b << '\n';

}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Заголовок, который используется для precompiled headers, в Visual Studio, всегда должен быть первой строчкой в файле, в который он включается. Это требование появилось потому, что всё, что идёт до этого включения игнорируется.

Поэтому, чтобы решить Вашу проблему, необходимо сделать `#include "stdafx.h"` первой строчкой в файле.